# Intellij IDEA: VCS markers on files

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Is there a setting or a plugin to display VCS markers on files in the project view ?

Here is what i'm talking about (Subversive/Subclipse on Eclipse):
[image]

(I am mainly asking for Subversion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no markers, but colors. As far as I remember, black is "updated", red — "conflict", "green" — added, but not comitted, "blue" — modified. Something like this.

All these colors will appear after you'll select VCS for your project or for a directory in your project. It can be done in Project Settings.